# Optimizing auto-complete FULLTEXT SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, database, full-text-search, query-optimization

I have the following query which is used in order to do an auto-complete of a search box:

```
  SELECT *, MATCH (screen_name, name) AGAINST ('+query*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS SCORE 
  FROM users 
  WHERE MATCH (screen_name, name) AGAINST ('+query*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
  ORDER BY SCORE DESC LIMIT 3
```

I also have a FULL TEXT index on screen_name & name (together). When this table was relatively small (50k) this worked great. Now the table is ~200k and it takes seconds(!) to complete each query. I'm using MySql MyISAM. Is this reasonable? What directions might I check in order to improve this as surely it doesn't satisfy the needs of an auto-complete query.

Comment: How many rows matches WHERE clause?

Comment: You might need to change to a third party text index like Sphinxsearch.com

Comment: @Karolis it depends on the query. If it's just one-two letters than a lot. Shoudl queries with less results be a lot easier to compute?

Answer (score 0):

MYSQL Match against is really slow, you should look into alternatives like [Sphinx Search Server](http://sphinxsearch.com/).